# catkin: build debendencies library of two other libraries

Tags: ros, catkin, target-link-libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Community,

i have some troubles with a Library which is dependend on two others.
I have added them all to CMakeLists.txt of my Package, it compiles correct but linking doesn't work.

Here the relevant parts of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
    link_directories(src/vPoint/ src/lsd/)
    
    add_library(MSAC
        src/vPoint/MSAC.h
        src/vPoint/MSAC.cpp
        src/vPoint/lmmin.h
        src/vPoint/lmmin.c
        src/vPoint/errorNIETO.h
        src/vPoint/errorNIETO.cpp
    )
    
    add_library(LSDLIB
        src/lsd/lsd.h
        src/lsd/lsd.c
    )
    
    add_library(FEATURES
        src/feature.cpp
        src/featureConstants.cpp
        include/open_cv_testing/feature.h
    )

add_executable(lsdnode src/lsd_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(FEATURES LSDLIB MSAC ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(lsdnode FEATURES ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

With the Features Library only dependent from MSAC everything worked, but now also with LSDLIB library.
It says while Linking it undefined resource lsd(...) but it's well defined with lsd.h and lsd.c.

Any Help what I'm missing appreciated...

The acutall error output is:

```
/home/martin/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libFEATURES.so: undefined reference to `lsd(int*, double*, int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/martin/catkin_ws/devel/lib/open_cv_testing/lsdnode] Error 1
make[1]: *** [open_cv_testing/CMakeFiles/lsdnode.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm using ROS Groovy in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

LSD Library from here: http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/gjmr-lsd/
Invoking in my Features Source code as in their call example, which runs without troubles...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212445/catkin:-build-debendencies-library-of-two-other-libraries/) by [Kersm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22975/kersm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-06-30**:
can you please post the actual error output? Furthermore: OS, ROS-Distro, ...

**Comment by [Kersm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22975/kersm/) on 2015-06-30**:
hi, thanks for your answer, hope i have added enough information now

**Comment by [Kersm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22975/kersm/) on 2015-06-30**:
Just found out that the problem, is not the Library which uses two Librarys.
I made a test node, which uses the LSD Lib directly (without the FEATURES Lib) and there is the same problem with the undefined reference: target_link_libraries(lsdtest LSDLIB {catkin_LIBRARIES})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wow, that was a wild one ;-)

The LSD library is ANSI C. So when you compile this you have to tell the linker to link in a C library.
I did a bit of googling and here is what worked for me  (actually, pretty simple). But whether this is the best or correct way, I cannot say.
Wrap the include statement of the lsd header in an `extern "C"` call.

```
extern "C" {
#include <lsd.h>
}
```

Hope this works.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kersm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22975/kersm/) on 2015-06-30**:
Thank you so much!
Obviously i googled wrong, this problem kept me going for 3days before i asked here...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-06-30**:
glad to help.